# access a coordinate in a nested \tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates

In the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node(inset) {
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate(v) at (3, 4);
        \node(t) at (v){v};
        \draw[->] (1,2) -- (v);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    };
    \node(t2)[blue] at (v){v};
    \draw[->, red](5, -2) -- (v);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I try to draw an arrow to a specific point corresponding to `\coordinate` "v" in a nested `\tikzpicture`.

From the result it appears that `\coordinate` "v" has walked.

[image]

How to fix?

Comment: where should `remember picture` be placed?

Comment: doesn' t appear to work

Comment: I do not know if there is a solution to your problem! - but do you know that nested tikzpictures are discouraged and are not guaranteed to work?

Comment: Why do you nest the `tikzpicture`s in the first place?

Comment: it is because I need to access `east` and `center` coordinates of the nested picture - to put elegant labels pointing to contents of the nested picture. As far as I know these coordinates are accessible only from outside (after the nested picture has been finished).

Comment: I think you're doing that the wrong way though, see if my answer is useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of nesting `tikzpicture`s, use a `local bounding box`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=inset]
        \coordinate(v) at (3, 4);
        \node(t) at (v){v};
        \draw[->] (1,2) -- (v);
\end{scope}
  \node(t2)[blue] at (v){v};
  \draw[->, red](5, -2) -- (v);

\draw [red] (inset.east) -- (inset.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Using a `scope` is an acceptable (better) alternative to a nested `\tikzpicture`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use saveboxes to safely nest tikzpictures, and the coordinates will be remembered.  The way `[remember picture]` works is to save the origin location in the aux file, so you have to run the code twice.

It should be noted that by placing the picture inside a node you are centering it (default) at the node location (origin).

```
\documentclass{article}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\sbox0{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
        \coordinate(v) at (3, 4);
        \node(t) at (v){v};
        \draw[->] (1,2) -- (v);
        \end{tikzpicture}
}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node(inset) {\usebox0};
    \node(t2)[blue] at (v){v};
    \draw[->, red](5, -2) -- (v);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 1):

Try \tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]

```
\documentclass{article}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node(inset) {
      \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
       \coordinate(v) at (3, 4);
       \node(t) at (v){v};
       \draw[->] (1,2) -- (v);
      \end{tikzpicture}
    };
    \node(t2)[blue] at (v){v};
    \draw[->, red](5, -2) -- (v);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: this solution worked

Comment: This is most unwise. Nesting `tikzpicture`s is not supported. Period. If it happens to work, that's coincidence and it is liable to break any time.